# how to register graphx Edge class with Kryo?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx, kryo

I've been trying to register Edge class with Kryo but I'm always getting the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge\nNote: To register this class use: kryo.register(org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge.class);
```

what is wrong with following line?

```
sc.getConf.registerKryoClasses(Array(Class.forName("org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge")))
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had trouble getting `graphx` classes registered.  This finally works for me...

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphXUtils

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("yourAppName")
GraphXUtils.registerKryoClasses(conf)
```

Here's what's going on behind the scenes...

https://github.com/amplab/graphx/blob/master/graphx/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/graphx/GraphKryoRegistrator.scala

In your case...  I'm not sure why the following wouldn't work fine, since `Edge` is exposed...

```
conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[Edge]))
```

But I **think** there are private classes in graphx that aren't exposed through the spark API, at least I see them in the graphx repo, but not the spark.graphx repo.  In my case, I couldn't get `VertexAttributeBlock` registered, until I used the GraphXUtils method.